# Trying to show a positioned DIV with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to show a div positioned relative to where the link is that the user clicks.

The link the user clicks is actually generated dynamically as well and looks like so.

```
<td><a href='' onClick="showDiv(14)">Show the div</a></td>
```

(14 is the ID of the record in the row which I will need for the DIV)

Here's my showDiv() function

```
function showDiv(id){

// get the mouse coordinates of the link
var mouseX;
var mouseY;

$(document).mousemove( function(e) {
   mouseX = e.pageX; 
   mouseY = e.pageY;
   $('#myDiv').show().css({'top':mouseY,'left':mouseX});
});  
}
```

This is showing my DIV when executed, but not relative. I feel I am a bit off here, JS is not my strength.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've went ahead and made [a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6XN8D/) with a solution to your problem.

The key is to bind your function to the click handler:

**Javascript**

```
$("selector to your element").click(function(e) {
   mouseX = e.pageX;
   mouseY = e.pageY;

  $("#myDiv").show().css({'top':mouseY,'left':mouseX});
});
```

Also as documented in the fiddle, the div should be hidden with `display:none;`

I went ahead and extended this a little myself, because perhaps you would like to hide the div by clicking the link again? You can find that in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hXm37/1/).

Comment: Hmm, I guess I should have been more specific in my example, but the clickable links which will show the DIV are dynamically generated through a JSON call. For some reason, it is not working on the dynamic links. I've confirmed it works outside of those.

Comment: AJAX is definitely tricky in javascript, I'll go ahead and create a demo to demonstrate this

Comment: I think it's having a hard time binding the click function to the class that the link has if the link is not yet built. I wonder if I need to move this out of my document.ready and into it's own function?

Comment: Brenton, I got it. You have to use on() instead of click()

Answer (score 3):

A few issues with your code:

```
<a href="showDiv(14)">
```

Don't do that. If anything, it should be `javascript:showDiv(14)`. You should use the `onclick` attribute or do it using jQuery's [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event. You also didn't end the `<a>` tag.

```
<td><a href='' onClick="showDiv(14)">Show the div</td>
```

should be

```
<td><a href="#" onClick="showDiv(14)">Show the div</a></td>
```

Another issue: `$('##myDiv')` should be `$('#myDiv')`.

**The solution:**

First, the div must be positioned absolutely.

```
#myDiv {
    position: absolute;
}​
```

That's the only way you can give it specific X and Y coordinates for position.

I also changed your link to

```
<a href='#' class="showTooltip">Show the div</a>
```

so I can simply use jQuery to bind to the click event of all links with the `showTooltip` class.

Finally the jQuery:

```
$(".showTooltip").click(function() {
    var left = $(this).position().left;
    var top = $(this).position().top;
    $('#myDiv').css({
        top: top + 5 + "px",
        left: left + 5 + "px"
    }).show();

});
```

`$(this)` refers to the element that was clicked. I am able to get its position and then set the `myDiv`'s position just as you had. I also added `5px` extra to the top and left just to show you how to offset it.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gUy3h/2/)

Comment: My mistake, I actually didn't copy and paste that from the code and typed it up real quick, it is correct in my code and i've edited the post :)

Comment: OK, I'll edit my answer with the solution to your problem in a sec.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response sachleen - I'll give this a go and mark as the answer as you provided a demo. Thanks again.